# Adding new test with SenTestCase (new test not showing up in manage scheme)

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing

So I'm trying out this new TDD thing (about time haha). Anyways I have two unit testing files currently one for application and one for logic. The application logic test was autogenerated by xcode and when I go to manage schemes I can see the (void)testExample but I can't see the other tests I have created in my logic file, nor are they being run. Attaching picture.[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it would help to read the docs a bit more carefully: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/03-Writing_Test_Case_Methods/writing_tests.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH4-SW1

You just have to prepend your methods with 'test'.

i.e.

```
-(void)testmynewcase {

}
```